# Nunit does not recognize Concordion.NUnit addin

Tags: nunit, concordion

Steps taken:
I downloaded and install NUnit.
I downloaded Concordion.NET.
I downloaded the Concordion.NET kickstarter (zip)
I verified that the specification (HelloWorld.html) is marked as an embedded resource.
I verified that the RequiredAddin("ConcordionNUnitAddin") assembly attribute was specified. 
I built the solution 
I copied the Concordion.NUnit.dll into the addin directory of my NUnit installation (C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\addins). 
I loaded the kickstarter solution in NUnit GUI runner.

Issue:
NUnit does not recognize the Spec project containing the specifications, i.e. the Spec assembly is marked as non-runnable. (It runs the actual (NUnit) unit tests fine.)

My expectation is that NUnit will recognize the Kickstart.Spec project and that when I run the tests, the results of those test will be indicated in the passed/failed information. Currently, as the project is not recognized, only the success of the NUnit unit test (ShouldGreet) is present.

Are my expectations incorrect, or is there some additional set-up step I missed necessary to get the process running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use NUnit 2.6.3 for the current release of Concordion.NET.
Unfortunatelly, NUnit addins are version dependent (http://nunit.org/index.php?p=extensionTips&r=2.6.4). This is also stated in the documentation of NUnit: "Most of the add-in samples provided with NUnit are currently version dependent."

NUnit 2.6.4 was released on December 16th, 2014. Future releases of Concordion.NET will support this version as well.

Thank you for providing your feedback - the documentation of Concordion.NET needs to be updated as well to include the information which version of NUnit is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could use the NuGet package of Concordion.NET (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Concordion.NET/) for your Visual Studio projects, which would ensure that you use always the right references of NUnit in your projects.